# Python get time from gpsd when no fix (ublox lea-6T gps)

Tags: python, gps

I am using gpsd.  I have a UBlox LEA-6T gps.  When it cold starts, I get time information long before I get my first location fix.  The time info looks like this (using gpspipe -r):

```
$GPGGA,191917.60,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*66
$GPRMC,191917.70,V,,,,,,,050415,,,N*79
$GPVTG,,,,,,,,,N*30
$GPGGA,191917.70,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*67
$GPRMC,191917.80,V,,,,,,,050415,,,N*76
$GPVTG,,,,,,,,,N*30
```

Looking at the $GPRMC, you can see both the time (191917) and date (050415).  The "N" in the forth to last position means "No Fix".

I'm using Python and open the GPS like:

```
from gps import gps, WATCH_ENABLE, WATCH_NEWSTYLE
session = gps()
session.stream(WATCH_ENABLE | WATCH_NEWSTYLE)
```

However, I don't get any data until I have a fix.  Is there a way to get the gps time from gpsd when I don't have a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Time from the gpsd using the `gps` module from the gpsd project is from `self.utc` and `self.fix.time` from an instance, either from something you create, or a [gpsd client like Dan Mandle's](http://www.danmandle.com/blog/getting-gpsd-to-work-with-python/) which lead to something like....

`print("UTC & time ", gpsdata.utc, ' ', gpsdata.fix.time)`

As I recall, `utc` is epoch time converted via the function `isotime` imported from `misc.py` and `self.fix.time` is a ISO8601 string.

But, what you are seeing are NMEA sentences, While not new criticism, ESR made [some good points about NMEA](http://esr.ibiblio.org/?p=801) 6 years ago about the same time gpsd adopted JSON protocol.  The campaign continues with [NMEA Revealed](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/NMEA.html).

GPSD streams out a number of JSON object TPV (**T**ime-**P**osition-**V**elocity), SKY (satellite data), etc., as a compact, straight forward protocol.

The because of the JSON protocol, and future integration into the Python world let me recommend the [gps3 project](https://github.com/wadda/gps3) for working with gpsd and Python.

While it is still Alfa, it doesn't drag in as much historical cruft, and uses the same JSON naming structure for derived Python dictionaries, and works with *both* Python2 and Python3.

When placed in the same directory as your project it's straight forward as well.  `TPV =  {'time', 'alt', 'tag', 'climb', 'device', 'epc', 'epd', 'eps', 'ept', 'epv', 'epx', 'epy', 'lat', 'lon', 'mode', 'track', 'speed'}`

`SKY = {'hdop', 'vdop', 'pdop', 'gdop', 'tdop', 'xdop', 'ydop'}`...and so on.

```
import gps3

gps_connection = gps3.GPSDSocket()
gps_fix = gps3.Fix()

try:
    for new_data in gps_connection:
        if new_data:
            gps_fix.refresh(new_data)
            print(gps_fix.TPV['time'])
            print(gps_fix.TPV['lat'])
            print(gps_fix.TPV['lon'])
            print(gps_fix.SKY['gdop'])
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    gps_connection.close()
    print('\nTerminated by user\nGood Bye.\n')
```

Comment: Before I switch my code to gps3, can you confirm this will give me GPS time when there is no fix?  I believe my issue is GPSD doesn't send me data without a FIX.  (ie, I think my current code gives me everything it gets from GPSD, and GPSD is filtering out the NO FIX data.)  Your code example doesn't explicitly show a different connection configuration with GPSD, so I presume it will behave the same? Or does gps3 open a more 'raw' connection to GPSD without the filter? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: @proximous, gps3, like gpsd, doesn't create something is not there, but neither sequester something that is there if asked.  I cannot confirm anything at the moment as both gps units I test are so hot they have a fix before I look up from the keyboard.  You could see for yourself by downloading gps3.py and using the code pasted above.  Does it do what you want?  There is always gpsd's JSON object, `device:activated` a timestamp when the gps was recognised, but then you're into system time.